# ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a scene to register, then another scene to play, and the last one is the ranking scene. But when i try to jump from the register scene, to the ranking scene to see the score without register first.
It says (ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: s

How can i fox this error, to allow me see the ranking scene first before play.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AddScore : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start(){
        AddPScore (0);
    }
    void AddPScore(int storeResult){
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        form.AddField ("user", LoginSystem.userName);
        form.AddField ("score", storeResult);
        WWW w = new WWW ("https://nfx.000webhostapp.com/AddScore.php",form);
        StartCoroutine (receive (w));
        Debug.Log("funcionou");
    }
    IEnumerator receive(WWW w){
        yield return w;
        if (w.error == null) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it tell you what line the error is on?

Comment: In previous version of Unity, I was having issue with passing WWW object as parameter. They often ended up null in the method tough the object was valid in the call. It could related to the inner implementation of the WWW class. All in all, you may want to move the WWW request into the receive method and remove the parameter

Comment: ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes (System.String s) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Text/Encoding.cs:268)
UnityEngine.WWWForm.AddField (System.String fieldName, System.String value, System.Text.Encoding e)
UnityEngine.WWWForm.AddField (System.String fieldName, System.String value)
AddScore.AddPScore (Int32 storeResult) (at Assets/LoginSystem2/Scripts/AddScore.cs:15)
AddScore.Start () (at Assets/LoginSystem2/Scripts/AddScore.cs:11)